# Assocation not found despite the fact I include "belongs_to" in my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, belongs-to

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I’m having trouble getting an association to appear in my view, despite the fact I included a “belongs_to” clause in my model.  In my app/models/my_object_time.rb file I have

```
class MyObjectTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :my_object
end
```

In my controller, I return a number of those objects into the view with

```
    @user_my_object_times = MyObjectTime.joins(:my_objects).where("my_object.user_id = #{session['user_id']}")
```

Then in my view, I call this

```
<% @user_my_object_times.each do |my_object_time| %>
    <tr>
            <td><%= my_object_time.my_object.name %></td>
```

but I get the error

```
Association named 'my_objects' was not found on MyObjectTime; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** In respones to the edit given, I edited my query like so

```
@user_my_object_times = MyObjectTime.joins(:my_objects).where("my_objects.user_id = #{session['user_id']}")
```

Unfortunately, I still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Association named 'my_objects' was not found on MyObjectTime; perhaps
>   you misspelled it?

You should use `:my_object` as you have `belongs_to` association. Also in the `where` clause, always use the ***pluralized name of the relation (actually, the table's name)***. So your query would be

```
@user_my_object_times = MyObjectTime.joins(:my_object).where("my_objects.user_id = #{session['user_id']}")
                                           #^ singular         ^ plural
```

Comment: I changed the query to what you suggested but I still get the error.  I think that's because I haven't done anything given your comment, "You should use :my_object".  Use that where?

Comment: @Dave In the `joins(:my_object)`

Comment: Ok, so I only made one change (edited my question to include the query ... beginning with @user_my_object_times = ...) but I still get the same error.  When you threw in the word "also" in your answer, I got the impression I needed to make two changes, so I'm assuming I only need to make one change.

Comment: @Dave You are still using `.joins(:my_objects)`. Change it to `.joins(:my_object)`